# search arrays with NSPredicate to return results and matches

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Hi I'm using NSPredicate to search objects of NSArrays against a 5 elements array, and get the result back. But is there any way to get the matched results returned by NSPredicate as well as the string (among that 5 elements array) against which match succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

try like this ,

this predicate gives the array which not contains that substring.

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not SELF   contains '%@'",searchString];
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@" AhfjA ", @"test1", @"best", @"AntA", nil];
        NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate ];
        NSLog(@"%@",filteredArray );
```

O/P:-

```
(
    AhfjA,
    best,
    AntA
)
```

it gives the array which contains the substring

```
 NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF   contains '%@'",searchString];
            NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@" AhfjA ", @"test1", @"best", @"AntA", nil];
            NSArray *filteredArray  = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate ];
            NSLog(@"%@",filteredArray );
```

O/P:-

```
(

    test1,

)
```